# Correlation between original and downsampled dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a dateset which consists of a timestamp and  a column for some sensor data. Because the timestamp is of very high frequency(in milliseconds), i downsampled both the columns with some logic. Initially the number of rows was about 50k but after downsampling it is now 900 rows.

Now, I want to assess to what degree the new dataset resembles/relates to the original dataset. I thought of using correlation between the datasets.
First i imported the dataset as pandas dataframes and then applied the correlation function as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('Original File')
df2 = pd.read_csv('sampleDown File')
print(df['sensordata'].corrwith(df2['sensordata']))

#output: -0.008646
```

It is giving me a negative value.

My question is:
1. Is this the right process i am adopting to find out the degree of resemblance between the new dataset and the original dataset?
2. If not, what should be my approach?

Thank you

Comment: This belongs on stats.stackexchange.com as it isn't really a programming question

Comment: And know I don't think this the right approach. My first base would be to check the relative error some of basic statistics, comparative probability plots, and comparing the maximum likelihood estimations of the datatsets' best-fit distribution parameters